# How to access field value in property get() method

Tags: kotlin

Can I access the value of property in Kotlin get() method?

Consider following:

```
class MyTest {

    var test: String = "string"
        get() {
            logIt("Property accessed")
            return it
        }

}
```

The magic variable `it` does not exists. How am I supposed to access actual property value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magical variable `it` exists in lambdas. The magical variable used for accessing the property value is called `field`. See [the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) for more information.

```
var test: String = "string"
    get() {  
        logIt("Property accessed")
        return field
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The field value is in the variable called `field`:

```
    var test: String = "string"
    get() {
        logIt("Property accessed")
        return field
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyTest {
    var test: String = "string"
        get() {
            logIt("Property accessed")
            return field
        }
}
```

If you want to get access to the field's value in a getter or setter you can use the reserved word `field` for it.